# "docker pull/run hello-world" behind a proxy returns "connection refused" error (non-root mode, linux mint)

Tags: docker, proxy

**Edit (kind of solved)** - Just before trying something else, I've tried the same procedure (to be sure it still did not work) and it's failed (as expected). Then I've tried with the root/sudo way ("sudo docker run hello-world") and it has worked (more or less expected). Finally for unknown reason it then worked properly when invoking with the non-root way ("docker run hello-world"). It looks like it needed to go to the root/sudo way to somehow "unlock" the non-root way so that it actually uses the proxy ; weird.

---

I am behind a proxy. I've followed the steps on Docker doc at https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/ as "non-root".

When I do the following,

```
$ docker pull hello-world
```

I get

```
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp x.x.x.x:443: connect: connection refused
```

(IP was changed to "x" chars).

Configuration:

- Linux mint Vanessa (based on Ubuntu 22.04).
- Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701

---

```
$ systemctl --user show --property=Environment docker
```

returns

```
Environment=PATH=/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.domain.org:8080 HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy.domain.org:8080
```

so it looks like proxy is actually recognized by docker (as it shows in the doc).

I am sure I can pass through the proxy with the following demonstration:

No proxy => connection refused:

```
$ export http_proxy= && export https_proxy=
$ curl -vv registry-1.docker.io
*   Trying x.y.z.a:80...
* connect to x.y.z.a port 80 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying x.y.z.b:80...
* connect to x.y.z.b port 80 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying x.y.z.c:80...
* connect to x.y.z.c port 80 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to registry-1.docker.io port 80 after 124 ms: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to registry-1.docker.io port 80 after 124 ms: Connection refused
```

With proxy => that's OK:

```
$ export http_proxy=http://proxy.domain.org:8080 && export https_proxy=http://proxy.domain.org:8080
$ curl -vv registry-1.docker.io
* Uses proxy env variable http_proxy == 'http://proxy.domain.org:8080'
*   Trying x.y.z.a:8080...
* Connected to proxy.domain.org (x.y.z.a) port 8080 (#0)
> GET http://registry-1.docker.io/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: registry-1.docker.io
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< content-length: 0
< location: https://registry-1.docker.io/
< Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Age: 0
< Date: Thu, 25 Aug 2022 15:57:15 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host proxy.domain.org left intact
```

Comment: Did u try restarting the docker service ?

Comment: @sidharthvijayakumar ; yes, "systemctl --user daemon-reload" and "systemctl --user restart docker" (no errors) then retried "docker pull hello-world", connection still refused.